# Content wider than browser width breaks page format

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]

When the contents of the page are wider than the browser window, and the browser is wider than the `min-width`, the wide elements will extend beyond the page's layout instead of stretching the layout to accommodate them.

The whole page is in a `<div id="container">` wrapper, which has a `min-width` of 990px, and a `width` of 100%

I'd like to fix the stylesheet for the site so that if an element is too wide for it, the layout will stretch. Right-aligned elements should stay all the way to the right, the menu bar should continue, the background should extend, etc.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGgHb.png):

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `min-width : 990px;` add `width : 990px;` instead then add `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't solve the problem, plus now the menu bar will wrap onto a second line if the window is narrower than it.